# Product UX vs Project UX

Tags: gui-design, user-behavior, product-design, project

As we know there is a common false assumption that

> UX means just the interface

But according to that [article](http://atiqurrehman.com/what-is-user-experience/) UX means totally different. Let's suppose if UX means interaction then how we will differentiate that interaction for a Product and a Project, If UX means user's feelings then how we will differentiate these feelings for a Product and a Project comparatively.

As well as the goal of a better **UX is to make users effective**. Then how the efficiency of a user will be considered in the case of product and project ?

And also what will be the basic parameters and **what about the UX cycle for both** product and project !

*(The product or project may be smart app, desk app or web app)*

Comment: You may need to further define the difference between a product and a project as you see it. For me a product would be the entirety of a system/service/app... etc. Whereas a project would be one aspect of a product - "Fix the shopping cart experience", "Reduce abandonment" are projects for me.

Comment: Project releases are often big-bang, all-or-nothing style of releases. Projects can often take months or even years to release. The software tasks are typically tracked with gantt charts and is often managed in a waterfall-style. 

While Product releases on the other hand, typically do not have a finite end date. Developers typically take more pride in their work. They know that the shortcuts they take today will affect them in the near future. The most important component is this model is working software.

Read More: [link](http://java.dzone.com/articles/product-vs-project)

Comment: @AtiqUrRehman that linked article is simply a really poorly written article. The author is actually talking about Waterfall methodology vs. Agile (MVP) methodology. If you google "UX and Agile" you'll find a lot of information out there--albeit a lot of conflicting information as how to fit UX into Agile is still something the industry is trying to figure out and ultimately depends heavily on the particularities of your specific organization and team makeup.

Comment: @DA01, Check the improved question.

Comment: @AtiqUrRehman I think the product vs. project distinction is purely arbitrary. Darryl's answer is pretty spot on: UX shouldn't care if it's defined as a project or a product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether it is a product or a project, the UX should be identical. That is to say that, both product and project require the best possible UX, which comes from research and lots of testing.

Just because a project is a 'one' time release, doesn't make it any less important to have a great UX. The main difference I can see in the UX process is that a product will likely have different personas from a project so some decision might be different. But this is totally dependant on the application you're working on.

Answer (score 2):

Userexperiencerocks website illustrate it perfectly like this, no software in sight.

[image]

Comment: where is the answer of my question in that photo ?

Comment: The answer is, there is no difference. But then, if you have to ask...

Comment: Love it, going to be using that myself!